# If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches

Tags: android, data-binding

I got in trouble to use dataBinding with google codelab.
It happened when I tried using below function.

```
    @BindingAdapter("app:hideIfZero")
    fun hideIfZero(view: View, number: Int) {
        view.visibility = if (number == 0) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
    }
```

I called it in xml like the following code.

```
    <ProgressBar
        ...
        app:hideIfZero="@{viewmodel.likes}"
        ... />
```

The viewModel is like the below.

```
class SimpleViewModel : ViewModel() {
    ...
    private val _likes = MutableLiveData(0)

    ...
    var likes: LiveData<Int> = _likes
```

I already tried to remove all cache Android Studio produced 
but it didn't work what I intend.
So I think there is a problem I missed.

I tried thie codelab https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-databinding/#7 
and my repository is here https://github.com/libliboom/codelab-data-binding

Anyone who let me know the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue I reported owing to the following link.

https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-databinding/issues/11

You should add 'kotlin-kapt' that is annotation processor.
It was hard to figure out the issue clear.

I also updated my repository related to this issue in below link.
https://github.com/libliboom/codelab-data-binding/commit/a98e3dc6079f542a49698a4d717b71ad4737dfdf

I hope it helps someone who is struggling with this someday.
Good luck!

Comment: I already have "kotlin-kapt" plugin in my project, still I'm getting this error

Comment: I see, then can you let me know the error message? What did you get stuck for?

Answer (score 0):

I also already had the "kotlin-kapt" plug-in and was still receiving the error. However, changing my compileSDKVersion from 30 to 29 and lowering the version of

`implementation "androidx.activity:activity:$ActivityVersion"`

resolved the error.